# How does this actually reorder items in the list?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was searching for a way to reorder items in a wpf list using MVVM. I found those two code sample which look amazing:

- the [reorderableListBox](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/abif/branches/3.0.0.0/Base/sources/ReorderableListBox/ReorderableListBox.cs)
- and its [DropPreviewAdorner](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/abif/branches/0.0.0.1/Base/sources/ReorderableListBox/DropPreviewAdorner.cs)

I studied the code and understood how it use the `ItemsReorderedEvent` to notify whoever wants to handle it that the items in the `ListBox` have been reordered.

I just don't get how it does reorder.. In fact, I've tried the code in a simple application and, even if I handle the event, nothing in my UI actually moves in my collection.

I was supposing that I needed to add code in the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`. Playing with the `originalItem`, its index and the new index.

Since the code was already all written, I was wondering why I needed to complete it. And if I'm wrong and it actually does not require any more code from me, what am I missing?

Here is the code of my simple application:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> list { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        list.Add("one");
        list.Add("two");
        list.Add("three");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReorderableListBox_ItemsReordered(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sdags");
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReorderableListBoxProject_XavText" x:Class="ReorderableListBoxProject_XavText.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <local:ReorderableListBox ItemsSource="{Binding list}"  ItemsReordered="ReorderableListBox_ItemsReordered"/>

</Grid>
```

**EDIT**

Here it is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because it expects you to do it manually,

A while ago I needed the same thing and ended up writing a small one.

There's no whistles and bells in it but it does its job.

[image]

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ReorderableListBox
{
    public class ReorderableListBox : ListBox
    {
        private bool _canDrag;
        private int _sourceIndex;
        private int _targetIndex;

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

            if (Items == null || SelectedItem == null) return;
            if (_canDrag)
                _sourceIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

            if (_targetIndex == -1 || _sourceIndex == -1 || !_canDrag) return;
            var item1 = (ListBoxItem)Items[_targetIndex];
            var item2 = (ListBoxItem)Items[_sourceIndex];
            object content1 = item1.Content;
            object content2 = item2.Content;
            item1.Content = content2;
            item2.Content = content1;

            _canDrag = false;
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);

            var canDrag = e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed;
            if (canDrag && Items != null && SelectedItem != null)
                _targetIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
            _canDrag = canDrag;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's very simple but effective, feel free to add Adorner, previews etc ..

**EDIT**

You need to wrap items in a ListBoxItem

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
foreach (int i in enumerable)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem {Content = i});
}
```

I've tried to *upgrade* the code by removing the cast to allow any type of object, unfortunately it doesn't works reliably, one would need more time to fix it. (I don't have that time)

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't work for me. I'm unable to cast anything (from String to my custom object) to ListBoxItem. It gives a " 'System.InvalidCastException' "

Comment: It does work for any type of object, post the relevant code that you can't get to work and I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Replaced

```
var item1 = (ListBoxItem)Items[_targetIndex];
var item2 = (ListBoxItem)Items[_sourceIndex];
```

on

```
ListBoxItem item1 = (ListBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_targetIndex);
ListBoxItem item2 = (ListBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_sourceIndex);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-get-a-listboxitem?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I'll switch to Russian, sorry
У меня предложенный выше код тоже не работал - возвращал значение типа string - название элемента. Что дальше нужно было делать с этим значением, не понятно.  В то время как

(ListBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_targetIndex);

Возвращает контейнер элемента, в том числе и сложный, например, созданный с помощью Style и DataTemplate. И уже с этим объектом код становится полностью работающим
То есть код будет выглядеть так:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace ReorderableListBox
{
public class ReorderableListBox : ListBox
  {
    private bool _canDrag;
    private int _sourceIndex;
    private int _targetIndex;

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

        if (Items == null || SelectedItem == null) return;
        if (_canDrag)
            _sourceIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

        if (_targetIndex == -1 || _sourceIndex == -1 || !_canDrag) return;
        ListBoxItem item1 = (ListBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_targetIndex);
        ListBoxItem item2 = (ListBoxItem)ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_sourceIndex);
        object content1 = item1.Content;
        object content2 = item2.Content;
        item1.Content = content2;
        item2.Content = content1;

        _canDrag = false;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);

        var canDrag = e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed;
        if (canDrag && Items != null && SelectedItem != null)
            _targetIndex = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
        _canDrag = canDrag;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).